# Calculate count of number of switch in vector

Tags: r

I have a vector in which i have to calculate how many times data switched from 0 to 100 and back to 0. An example is given as below.

```
Input
X1<-c(100,100,100,0,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,100,100,0,0,0,0,100,100,100,0,0,100,100)
```

So the output should be **3** as the value started at 0 stayed at 100 for the some time and back to 0. My requirements is to count how many times this switch has occurred. I am aware of rle but that only gives me the length.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Or since you mention rle  `floor(length(rle(X1)$lengths)/2)`

Comment: @Anish, should the expected answer be **2** since you don't know if the last run of `100` switched back to `0`? Maybe you're only looking for switches from `0` to `100`?

Comment: @ChiPak yes, i believe since I do not have control on the last or even first element.

Answer (score 2):

This looks sufficient

```
sum(X1[-1] != X1[-length(X1)]) / 2
```

Assumptions are that

- You only have two unique values in `X1`
- The last element of `X1` equals the first element, that is, it switches back to original state in the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like,

```
sum(diff(X1) == 100)
#[1] 3

#Or

min(sum(diff(X1) == 100), sum(diff(X1) == -100))
#[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You could run `rle` and then iterate through three elements of `values` at a time to see if the required condition has been met.

```
with(rle(X1),
     sum(sapply(3:length(lengths), function(i)
         values[i-2] == 0 & values[i-1] == 100 & values[i] == 0)))
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

more generally for counting switches in n cases (numeric or character):

```
 count_switches_groups <- function(seq.input){
  COUNT <- 0
  transition = rep("no switch",length(seq.input))
  for (i in 2:length(seq.input)) {
    if (seq.input[i] != seq.input[i - 1]) {
      COUNT <- COUNT + 1
      transition[i] <- paste0("from ",seq.input[i - 1]," to ",seq.input[i])
    }
  }
  total_switches <- COUNT
  state_transitions <- transition[transition != "no switch"]
  occurances <- as.data.frame(table(state_transitions))
  return_list <- list(total_switches,occurances)
  names(return_list) <- c("total_transitions","unique_switches")
  return(return_list)
}
count_switches_groups(X1)
```

Answer (score 0):

sum((np.diff(x)==100)|(np.diff(x)==-100))

I think this would be the answer, worked for me